# Why won't iOS segmented control's color restore after select another segment

Tags: ios, objective-c, colors

[image: Picture]
<sub>(source: [clouddn.com](http://7xpaek.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/W7LFsuLWup.gif))</sub>

This is a problem in chapter 6 of iOS programming 4ed. In origin application you can touch the screen to change circle color to a random color. And the problem ask you to add a segmented control of three item: red, green and blue. Click the segmented control and circle color should be changed to corresponding color.

In the process solving that problem, I of course add one segmented control. But as you can see in the gif, after being clicked, each segment's color won't restore and finally the whole segmented control becomes all blue.

But the `selectedSegmentIndex` acts just as it should.

*When I record the gif I've `//` the codes to control the color so circle color didn't change to red, green or blue. So don't mind the circle color since it is not red, green or blue.*

And here is the code I use to define the segmented control:

```
NSArray *segmentedControlTitle = @[@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue"];
self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentedControlTitle];
self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 150, 30);
[self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(controlChanged:) forControlEvents:1 << 12];
[self addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
```

And I found that if only the circle color doesn't change, segmented control color changes correctly. If only the circle color changes (no matter changed by touching the screen or by segmented control), segmented control color changes as in the gif.

So why would that happen? Is this a bug or is there anything I did not accomplish?

All source code [here](https://github.com/zhengbuqian/Hypnonerd/blob/master/HypnoNerd/BNRHypnosisterView.m))

Comment: U want to change colour of selected segment?

Comment: Your code heve not got a mistake, can U add a controlChanged: method code?

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck no, as the gif shows, at first I select red, so 1st segment becomes blue (means that it is selected); then I select green, so 2nd segment becomes blue, but the problem is that 1st segment is still blue, its background should become transparent.

Comment: i use your code and i haven't got this bug, maybe u use self.segmentedControl in any place?

Comment: `controlChanged:` at first has some codes to change circle's colour, but afterwards I delete all those codes except one line of `NSLog` so this segmented control has no function anymore.

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck You can see all my source code [here](https://github.com/zhengbuqian/Hypnonerd/blob/master/HypnoNerd/BNRHypnosisterView.m), you can see I didn't use it in any other place except for `drawRect:` and `controlChanged:`.

Comment: you should use your segment control init code in - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame { , try simply cut and past your code in this method, and tell me helped or not

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck I didn't create a subclass of segmented control so I got nowhere to override this method( or maybe because I don't know where to place, new to iOS). I tried this `self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:segmentedControlFrame]` and then insert some segments, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U need one line

```
if (!self.segmentedControl) {  // THIS LINE
    CGRect segmentedControlFrame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 150, 30);
    self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:segmentedControlFrame];
    //self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 150, 30);
    [self.segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"red" atIndex:0 animated:NO];
    [self.segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"green" atIndex:1 animated:NO];
    [self.segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"blue" atIndex:2 animated:NO];
    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(controlChanged:) forControlEvents:1 << 12];
    [self addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
}
```

Because every time then U change colour of circle, you re-init your segment control for example u tap to screen 10 times and U call - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 10 times, and u have 10 segmentedControls one over another))

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :D